# An example for assiging value to the field 55 in iso 8583

Tags: iso8583, jpos, tlv

Does anyone has an example for assigning value to the 55th Field (Reserved ISO) in the ISO 8583 messages where it should be assigned with a TLV value?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to handle your field 55 as an opaque field (just a `byte[]`) and then use some of the `org.jpos.tlv.*` classes to create your TLV field.

Once you 'pack' your TLV field (using `tlv.pack()`) you can set that `byte[]` into your ISOMsg's field 55, i.e.:

`m.set(55, tlv.pack());`

Comment: Thanks for your help ! :) but how can i set the 55th field value !

Comment: any idea about this one ! I'd be grateful

Comment: You use `ISOMsg.set (55, byte[])` as described above.

Comment: I'm not sure if i totally understood what you described! I searched for example following what you mentioned but couldn't find any . Can you please provide a full example !

Comment: You use the ISOMsg.set method, using a `byte[]` as the second parameter. That will properly set the binary field.